# Show parent child relationship of taxonomy term in view

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am looking for a way to display the list of taxonomy terms in a view indenting the child tax terms. I need to be able to see all Taxonomy terms including the ones that do not have children terms. any ideas?

```
Domain 1 
    Sub-domain 1
    Sub-domain 2
Domain 2
    Sub-domain3
    Sub-domain4
Domain 3
Domain 4
```

I tried to follow the suggested solutions but they did not work out for me.  The first one in the link is asking you to provide a parent taxonomy term to filter by. I want to get the complete list.  the Second one only provide the Taxonomy terms that have a parent child relationship. I need to see all taxonomy terms even if they don't have children.  Here is the screenshot of my view setup, I followed the exact steps outlined by louieliu.  As you can see it only shows Environment with subchildren of Soil and Weather but does not show the other Domains without subchildren.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did a search but did not find this....Ill give it shot and close this one.

Comment: I followed what was suggested in this post "How to show the parent and child taxonomy term?" but it did not work.  I ended up with just the children showing.

Comment: @Russ You can edit your question to show us exactly how you set it up and how it failed. For now, it is a duplicate. I'll vote to close now, but if you'll edit it, comment @ me and I can always retract my vote (or vote to reopen)

Comment: I have updated the post. let me know if that was enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try [Views tree](https://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module.

Project page says

> This module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views. It is
>   equivalent to the tree-based style template from Views 1.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested
>   view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it
>   quite performant.
>
> Compatibility
>
> This module has been tested and used with the following
>   relationship-oriented modules:
>
> Taxonomy (in core) - parent/child relationships

Comment: Ok, after writing my own module to implement this, I figured out the views tree module DOES work. The module is a little picky with the way you set it up.  Thanks for the lead!